# What test and how test a storage layer implemented using JPA

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, jpa, dao

I want to test the storage layer of my application. The storage layer access the database and map the model with the database schema using JPA.

As example take a storage layer for an application that visualizes books. The model has two entities: books and authors. A book can have one or more authors. The storage layer exposes methods for listing books, authors or more complex operation like all the books for a certain author.

I'm trying to understand how and what I've to test in my storage layer.

**Database**

- Should I test the connection?

**Model**

- Should I test the model?
- Should I test the JPA annotations in the model? For example joins between books and authors.
- Should I test if the model matches the schema? For example fields and tables name.

**Storage logic (DAO)**

- Should I test the DAO?
- Should I test the DAO isolating it from the EntityManagerFactory?

**Storage layer**

- Should I make an integration test that comprises DAO, JPA and DB?
- Should I test the storage layer logic using a test DB?
- If I use a test DB should it be filled with well know data, created specifically for the test, in order to make the correct assertions in my tests? For example test that if I ask for all the books for author X I get all the books.
- Should I test methods like listing that simply delegate the operation to JPA?

Other questions and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Very broad topic and prone to personal experience and taste. I dont believe you can get a good answer for it here.

In reality, it is integration testing not unit testing. To do unit testing you have to mock almost everything.

Yes, your db should contain well known data. And it should contain not only data that you are using for particular test (for example only one author) but also other "sibling" data to catch the side effects, not unique results ...

There is a nice article about the data layer tests:
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/writing-tests-for-data-access-code/

Again, prone to discussion (so if someone disaggre please write your own answer and not engage in comments bouncing), but to be more specific:

- no point in testing connection, it will colapse other tests and with meaningul stacktrace. Also fact that you have connection in your test, does not mean you will have it in real code as it depends on perstitence configuration.
- how could you test your model. Getters and setters ... no. There are no joins in model, only object/collections references. To test for the proper mapping of your relation to db, you need DB backend and JPA handling them, so you cannot test the relations without integration test. If you have mismatch between fields and db tables, simple insert will raise the error. So yes you should at least persist one object, for the sake of mapping validation.
- yes you should test your retrieval/search methods. This is your integration test, and the only place where you can find if all the layers work as expected.

Comment: Do you think is worth testing simply method like listing? Its really necessary make an insert in order to test mapping or it is suffice for example list all the model entities?

Comment: Insert picks up problems with ID generation strategy, foreign keys/indexes constraints and such. I got errors caused by them surprisingly often, so I always try to persist entity, retrieve it and remove it. Don't know what you mean by simple listing, but if it is a wraper arround find all query I would say that no.